# Number of characters in a password in C

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, character

I'd like to write a code in C in which the number of characters of a password is declared but I don't know why after using the following algorithm, I get weird answers.

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main()
 {
   int n=1,i=0;
   char * pass[100];

   printf("Enter your pass: ");
   scanf(" %c",&pass);

   for (i=0; pass[i]!='0';i++){
       n++;
   }

   printf("number of characters: %d\n", n);

   return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: What do you mean by `char * pass[100];`

Comment: What is a "weird answer"? Please edit your post.

Comment: I'd like to add enter a hypothetical password as an array.
when I run this code and enter a string,very irrelevant answers come up.
for instance,when i type Hi,it shows 638 as the number of character.

and by char * pass[100]; I meant an array called pass with 100 positions.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to declare a string pointer to a character array. Instead of char * pass[100]; you can try char pass[100]; and even initialize the pass array with char pass[100] = "abc"; or something similar.

Comment: The `%c` in your scanf format string consumes exactly one _character_.  The argument of `%c` should be a pointer to an `int` where the character's code point will be stored.

Comment: The line containing for (i=0; pass[i]!='0';i++) won't work because you're trying to compare a character in the array with an integer. Convert the character to an integer with int('0') and look for the ASCII number for the '0' character instead. I would have the loop iterate the length of the string and do the comparison within the body of the loop. Otherwise, you can get some really strange results and even infinite loops. If you're searching for the null terminator, use '\0' instead of '0'. Also, what James said. You should input a string instead of a single character for the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with `char * pass[100]` is probably not what you want although it might work. You just need `char pass[100]`.

Secondly you are asking `scanf` to scan for a single character with the `%c` option. To read a whole string use the `%s` option.

Finally in the line:

   `for (i=0; pass[i]!='0';i++){`

`'0'` does not mean null, it refers to the character 0, i.e. 48 on the ascii charts. You are probably looking for `'\0'` which means null. Null is used to terminate the strings.